# How to remove elements from an array using arguments object - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, arguments

I am trying to remove elements from an array that is passed on a function as an argument. The elements that I am trying to remove from the array are the ones equal to the following arguments of the function. Like this: `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);` so if the array (first argument of destroyer) contains "2" and "3", I want them removed. So calling the function should return [1, 1].

```
function destroyer(arr) {

  var args = [];

  for(var j = 1; j<arguments.length; j++){

      args.push(arguments[j]);

    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){

        if(args.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1){

            arr.splice(i, 1)
        }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

I don't understand why my code works for `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);` (it returns [1, 1]) but not for `destroyer([2, 3, 2, 3], 2, 3);` (it should return [], but returns [3]).

Please, help me understand why this doesn't work.

I have created a repl.it at https://repl.it/BTu5

Comment: check my answer below bro, have created a repl for you, https://repl.it/BTu5/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the privous answer is right,
but i got something working , it's more similar to the question's code, help him to understand:
   code:

```
 function destroyer(arr) {

 var args = [];
  //You want add all the nums you want remove from array, so you start from 1, which means second arg,first arg is the array you want to perform
  for(var j = 1; j<arguments.length; j++){ 
  //You store the args to an arg array
      args.push(arguments[j]);
    //Once you have the arg, you want loop the target array, see if the newly added arg exist in the target array, if it is, then remove it
    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        //Found it, remove it now! note: your found the index, then you need take it out, check the doc for slice function arr.slice([begin[, end]]) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice
        if(args.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1){
            //key change, remove the element 
            arr.splice(i, i+1)
           }
       }
   }
  return arr;
  }
 destroyer([2, 3, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

`

Also, have created a play for you

https://repl.it/BTu5/5

example: slice(1,4) extracts the second element up to the fourth element (elements indexed 1, 2, and 3).

Comment: anyone down vote my answer? could you please leave a reason? my code is not optimized, but this is more close to the original code, which helps understanding

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Really appreciate the help. It's exactly what I needed. I knew I was close but didn't understand what I was missing. Could you explain what i + 1 does exactly?

Comment: @gregmarquet, no worries mate, pleasure to help you out, there will be better solution, but I think i am just trying best to help you understand and to learn, happy coding bro, dont forget to tick my answer as well, lol

Comment: Sure Kevin, I up voted your answer but it doesn't count since I just started. Also, I edited my previous comment and would love to really understand what the change you made ( i+1 instead of 1) did. How is it really working? How did you think of it, what is the logic behind it.

Comment: @gregmarquet, i am adding comments to it, will update soon bro! lol

Answer (score 0):

It's bad programming practice to update a collection while you are looping over it: the call to `arr.splice()` may change the value of `arr.length`. Try to add a `debugger;` statement to see what happens while your program runs.

This is a version that removes unwanted elements from the input array

```
/* Call like this:
 *   removeValues(list, 2, 3);
 *   removeValues(list, "foo", 4, "bar");
 */
function removeValues(collection) {
  var it = collection.splice(0); // clear + create iterator
  var unwanted = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < it.length; i++) {
    if (unwanted.indexOf(it[i]) < 0) {
      collection.push(it[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should at least leave the reason in a comment

Comment: bro, same thing happened to me as well, hate people down voting without leaving a message, eh?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you. Anyway it seems the downvoter changed his mind

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you just .filter()?

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  var badValues = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //Construct an array of arguments
  badValues.shift(); //Get rid of the first ("good") array element
  return arr.filter(function(x) {return badValues.indexOf(x) == -1;}); //Make "bad" values false and thus — filter them.
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this challenge using filter function, though t is recommended to use also 'indexOf' in order to compare value in array by the value to filter with. Try this)
````

```
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
    var temp = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        temp.push(arguments[i]);
        arr = arguments[0].filter(function(value) {
            return ( value !== temp[i - 1]) ;
        });
    }
    return arr;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I completed this Basic Algorithm Scripting Challenge at freeCodeCamp using [Arguments Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Hope this helps

```
function destroyer(arr) {
var args = [];
//Creating array of arguments
for(var j=1;j<arguments.length;j++){
    args.push(arguments[j]);
}
//Filtering the arguments from array
arr = arr.filter(function(val){
    if(args.indexOf(val)==-1)
        return true;
return false;
});
return arr;
```

}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

Answer (score 0):

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Make a copy of arr by using .slice() and an empty arr2 to put the elements that you want to remove 
  let arr1 = arr.slice()
  let arr2 = [];
  // here just iterate starting from 1 because 0 is the array that you want to modifie and push() to arr2
  for (let i = 1; arguments.length > i; i++) {
    arr2.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  // And here just filter arr1 with arr2, and that basically removes all arr1 elements that are present in arr2
  return arr1.filter(elem => !arr2.includes(elem));
}    
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).